# TeX4HT, first paragraph and indentation

Tags: indentation, tex4ht, htlatex

In a book, I set up indentation to be 1em for every paragraph, including the first paragraph in sections:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
```

However, TeX4HT doesn't honor this setting and sets the first paragraph to `noindent`.

How can I prevent TeX4HT from setting first paragraphs to `noindent`?

Comment: Will it honour the `indentfirst` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many `\noindent`s in `tex4ht`'s  configuration files, easiest way to solve this situation is to use custom CSS code to select `p.noindent` elements which are direct children of `body` (there are also `p.noindents` which are used in tables, theorems etc., where we probably don't want indentation)

Put this into custom config file or custom `4ht` file:

```
\Css{body > p.noindent{
text-indent:1em;
}}
```